# Gauss Law - tangential component discontinuity at dielectric boundary

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauss-law, dielectric

Let's say we have a dielectric slab $x < a, z > -1$ and a plane $z=-1$ with a surface charge of $\sigma$. Gauss law states that: $$\oint_S D dA = Q_{free}$$
Dielectric has no free charge so electric displacement field can be expressed as electric displacement field of a plane:
$$D = \frac{\sigma}{2}$$
Where $\vec{D}$ points in positive $z$ direction for $z > -1$. Then electric field along the x axis can be expressed as:
$$\vec{E(x)} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{z} & \textrm{for $ x > a $}\\
\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}\hat{z} & \textrm{for $ x < a $}\\
\end{array}\right.$$
Which causes a discontinuity at $x = a$ at the surface of a slab $x < a, z > -1$ but tangental component of $E$ field should be continious across the interface. What part of electrostatic theory am I missing?

Comment: What is D supposed to be? If there is surface charge then D is discontinuous.

Comment: If your surface is $z=-1$, whose normal is $\hat{z}$, then how is $\vec{E}$ along $\hat{x}$?

Comment: I'm talking about discontinuity of electric field across the boundry of dielectric slab and free space. Edited question a bit to add versors.

Comment: Isn't this the typical example of showing the dangers of applying Gauss's law for the electric displacement across a discontinuous boundary?

Comment: Maybe it is, I haven't been taught about those dangers. Can you give me some sources that explain why you can't do that?

Comment: There are 3 objects in this example, charged plane $z=-1$ dielectric slab $x<a,z>−1$ and vacuum everywhere else.

Comment: I don't have time to type out an answer. But if you have access to Griffith's Introduction to Electrodynamics, check out chapter 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is two surface $x=a$ and $z=-1$, so the surface integral can't simply be ordinary integral and in that way it is not that straight forward expression of $\vec{E}.$

Comment: I'm talking about discontinuity of electric field across the boundry of dielectric slab ($x < a, z > -1$) and free space.

Comment: Oh yes I see, then you can't simply evaluate the Gauss integral, as there is two surfaces. One $x=a$ and other $z=-1$. So the simplification of surface integral into proper integral will not be valid.

Comment: Dielectric doesn't have any free charges so it shouldn't affect the D field, is the equation for E field incorrect?

Comment: D is also a vector quantity, so you should figure out what is the direction of that vector. I think you can't or it is difficult because of the surface integral. The expression of $\vec{E}$ is correct, if $\vec{D}=\sigma/2\hat{z}$, but it think its not. $\sigma/2\hat{z}$ is when you have an infinite plane $x=a$, but its not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your equations for $\bf E$ do not apply at the edge the dielectric in this situation, owing to the polarization being in a direction different to $\bf D$ near the edge. However I have not worked it out fully so am not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

The tangential component of the electric field across the interface at $x=a$ is continuous, so your expressions for the E-field are incorrect.

If there is an intersection of a charged plane with a dielectric, then you cannot assume there is no field tangential to the charged plane as you would for a plane in a vacuum. There will be a tangential component to the conducting plane (i.e. a normal component to the dielectric plane) because the symmetry of the usual infinite charged plane problem is broken.